# Is there an equivalent function pytorch's loss fuction nn.crossEntropyLoss() in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'm converting conv2d model written by pytorch to keras(Tensorflow 2.0).

I've almost done, but last question is delaying my work.

The title says it all: is there an equivalent function pytorch's loss fuction nn.crossEntropyLoss() in keras?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on type of your labels and outputs, there are currently three different entropy losses supported in Keras.

**categorical_crossentropy**:

`keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0)`

**sparse_categorical_crossentropy**:

`keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, axis=-1)`

**binary_crossentropy**:

`keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0)`

You can find a full list of Keras losses [here](https://keras.io/losses/)

Comment: binary_crossentropy is definitely not the same as pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss. It's equivalent to pytorch's BCELoss.